# Bootstrap 3: Is there a way to hide navbar-text when small screens are used?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3.1.1.

I want the navbar-text to disappear on smaller screens. Currently, it looks disjointed on smaller screens. Preferably, it would just go away on smaller screens but as an alternative it could render nicely under the title.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">Brand</div>
            <p class="navbar-text">I want this text to disappear when screen is small</p>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <u1 class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Index</a></li>
            <li><a href="link1.htm">Link 1</a></li>
            </u1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/120371

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the [responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) such as the `hidden-sm` and `hidden-xs` classes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd suggest taking a look at the [Bootstrap 3 documentation - (Responsive utilities)](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

There are classes, such as `hidden-xs`, that can be used to hide elements for certain media queries. For example, `hidden-xs` will hide the element when the screen is less than 768 px.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pugL6/)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">Brand</div>
            <p class="navbar-text hidden-xs">I want this text to disappear when screen is small</p>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <u1 class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Index</a></li>
            <li><a href="link1.htm">Link 1</a></li>
            </u1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also use a combination of `visible-md`/`visible-lg` in order to hide the element when the screen is less than or equal to 992 px.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but this code was used on my website: logo collides navbar elements (about, product etc)

```
<a href="Index.html" class="navbar-brand hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-sm"><span style="color:red">UNITED</span> STATES OF AMERICA</a>
<a href="Index.html" class="navbar-brand visible-xs visible-md visible-sm"><span style="color:red">U</span>SA</a>
```

so brand goes from UNITED STATES OF AMERICA (responsive/resizing) to USA

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if those helper classes don't work for you (meaning they don't hide at the screen size(s) you like), if you're including a custom stylesheet you can include your own media queries to hide just the elements you want.